Where can I view the list of deployed OpenAI models in Azure?
Where can I view the list of deployed OpenAI models in Azure?
I thought it was under "Resource Management" but I don't see it anymore:


After looking for ~10 minutes, the "Model Deployment" suddenly reappeared under "Resource Management":

Then it disappeared again (reappeared/disappeared = upon page refresh or opening new tabs). I assume the Azure web UI is undergoing some issues/updates.
Since amazingly two days later the issue is still present, here's the direct link to model deployments: https://oai.azure.com/resource/deployments

I assume the Azure web UI is undergoing some issues/updates. When doesn't it? :/
